# nzec error in python 2.7 hackerearth

Tags: python

```
def selsort(l):
  for start in range(len(l)):
    pos = start
    for i in range(start,len(l)):
      if l[i] < l[pos]:
        pos = i                     
    l[pos],l[start]=l[start],l[pos] 
  return(l)

N = int(raw_input())
l = selsort([int(x) for x in(raw_input().split())])
num_of_keys = int(raw_input())
key_size = [int(x) for x in (raw_input().split())]   

f_list = [[] for x in range(num_of_keys)]  
pos = -1

for i in range(len(key_size)):
  for j in range(num_of_keys): 
    if len(f_list[j]) < key_size[j]:
      f_list[j].append(l[pos])
      pos = pos -1 


steps_required = 0
for i in range(num_of_keys):
  for j in range(key_size[i]):
    steps_required = steps_required + f_list[i][j]*(j+1)
```

#
    print steps_required

the above code gives Runtime error :NZEC using python 2.7. how to solve this. https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/selection-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/old-keypad-in-a-foreign-land-24/

Comment: What are `num_of_keys`, `key_size`? Please look into creating a [mcve]. What have you tried to debug this? Non-Zero Exit Code means your program crashed, probably getting an exception: please add that exception to the question as well.

Comment: ok thanks. will do the same and edit the above.

Answer (score -1):

i try the code with the example of the linked website

```
def selsort(l):
  for start in range(len(l)):
    pos = start
    for i in range(start,len(l)):
      if l[i] < l[pos]:
        pos = i                     
    l[pos],l[start]=l[start],l[pos] 
  return(l)

N = 4
l = selsort([7, 3, 4, 1])
num_of_keys = 2
key_size = [1,3]

f_list =[[] for x in range(num_of_keys)]  
pos = -1

for i in range(len(key_size)):
  for j in range(num_of_keys): 
    if len(f_list[j]) < key_size[j]:
      f_list[j].append(l[pos])
      pos = pos -1 

print(f_list)

steps_required = 0
for i in range(num_of_keys):
  for j in range(key_size[i]):
    steps_required = steps_required + f_list[i][j]*(j+1)
```

I think the assignment of the keys is wrong.

```
for j in range(max(key_size)):
    for i in range(num_of_keys):
        if(len(f_list[i])>=key_size[i]):
            continue
        f_list[i].append(l[pos])
        pos=pos-1
```

And so the index error is solved